# xbmc builds for pi can't browse and play videos from UPnP shares

Tags: kodi, streaming-video

**Context/Project**
I am building a carputer project and have been considering using the pi as it would require little power, is relatively inexpensive and be small enough to be tucked neatly away without going to a lot of trouble wiring the trunk. If I can't get XBMC to behave as expected, I will probably switch to a Hackberry A10.

**Problem**
First of all, I have found this problem on the latest Openelec for the pi as well as Xbian's latest beta and raspbmc. What happens is the following:

> 1) I install the xbmc-based distro on the pi's SD card
>   2) I go to Settings>Services and enable UPnP server, controlpoint, announcements, etc.
>   3) I go to Videos>Files>Add Videos... and add "UPnP Media Servers (Auto Discover)"
>   4) I select it, browse to my XBMC UPnP share from my desktop and try to play something. It doesn't display a message and it doesn't play any file (I tried every kind of file I have: music in aac and mp3, video in h264/aac and mpeg2/ac3)

At first I thought UPnP just didn't work. However, if I select the pis xbmc instance as a renderer from another control point and select any of the files (audio or video) that wouldn't play from the xbmc menu, they play beautifully.

Has anybody else had this problem? I can't figure out what's wrong as I've never had this issue on any other platform using xbmc! Is this at all similar to the UPnP bug found in Frodo 12.1 and 12.2 when trying to play a live stream from an HDHomerun Prime via UPnP? Is it requestins information that no other platform would request?